# Excel VBA - Multidimensional array into non-contiguous range (made using union of cells)

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to take a multidimensional array and place it into a range. But, the range is a split (non-contiguous) range and I need to be able to use `.Cells` and not the standard `.Range("A1")`.  My below code works somewhat, but only places in the 1st 2 instances of the array for each range in the Union.

Please see below:

```
 Dim TestArray(1 To 2, 1 To 3) As Integer
 TestArray(1, 1) = 1
 TestArray(2, 1) = 2
 TestArray(1, 2) = 3
 TestArray(2, 2) = 4
 TestArray(1, 3) = 5
 TestArray(2, 3) = 6

 Union(Range(Cells(78, 1), Cells(79, 1)), Range(Cells(78, 4), Cells(79, 4)), _
       Range(Cells(78, 6), Cells(79, 6))).Value = TestArray
```

My Results are as follows:

```
A78=1    
A79=2    
D78=1    
D79=2    
F78=1    
F79=2
```

I want my results like:

```
A78=1    
A79=2    
D78=3    
D79=4    
F78=5    
F79=6
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How generic does this need to be? There is no direct way to use `=` like you've tried so you'll probably need to write a helper function. How complicated that function is will depend on things like **1.** can you always guarantee the range will have the right number of rows/columns, **2.** Is the size of the array always the same, **3.** Are cells on the same row always touching, etc. If it's always as simple as your example, then assigning the 3 rows separately will do (as in Domenic's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
 Range("A78:A79").Value = Application.Index(TestArray, 0, 1)
 Range("D78:D79").Value = Application.Index(TestArray, 0, 2)
 Range("F78:F79").Value = Application.Index(TestArray, 0, 3)
```

Hope this helps!